PVG612AS, I do not understand connection C
I am a complete beginner in electronics. And now I'm working with photovoltaic relay PVG612. I see connection C  and do not understand how it works.
If I understand correct - when power goes to pin 1 - then relay change triggers and current goes on pins 6,5. Then when current stops, then triggers go back and current goes from 4,5. But on connection C pins 4 and 6 looped, so independently of trigger, current always same.
I am sure I am wrong in my logic. Can you help me understand how it really works?
Sorry for stupid question, but really can't find any article where it is explained for beginners like me.
Example of relay there - https://www.ebay.ca/itm/354022952219

The two MOSFETs are paralleled ... and double current. How did you control the current at the input?

On pin 1 - 3V current from batarry passing rezistor and something like button - on/off (enable/disable relay). On other side -  pins 4/6 has current from same battary - so 3V without any button.

If you ignore the bottom FET in the package and just look at the top one, is it more clear that it will just function as a high side switch for you?

I believe yes. If use only 6,5 pins. Then current will be on or off depending on current on pins 1,2

If you want to talk to EEs, "current on or off" on a switch is not language you will run into. Switches are open or closed. Whether current will flow or not depends on what's connected to it. In your case yes, but I would avoid this terminology.

You have understood the part wrong. It is not like a dual throw relay where either connections 6&5 or 4&5 alternate.
For switching DC, B and C connections only have one difference, in B only one FET is used, in C, two FETs are used in parallel.
Either both 6&5 and 4&5 are both on, or they are both off.
You can parallel the two FETs to be able to switch more current or achieve lower resistance.

Thank you! This is what I was need to understand!
